# Select query on hive not displaying the records initially

Tags: hive

I recently ran a hive create-table-select statement and it completed normally.

- When I try to query the table, the query returns 0 records but the HDFS path has the files.
- The same query returns the records when I query it after a couple of hours.

Can someone tell me if there is some property that needs to be changed? There was absolutely nothing that was done in between these two events.

Comment: Given the information you've provided, its nearly impossible to answer this question.  What is the create table statement?

Comment: It was a normal create table statement. We were able to find the cause of this - TEZ engine. Working on resolving it.